# How to reload a web page with new events in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web page that controls some .cmd file. There is a label in my web that show an error message when any error happens in the batch file. Now I want that when the label show the error message, the web page will be reload with some new events like textbox, dropdown list etc... How can I do this? 
I am a beginner. Please Help.

Comment: What error message? What cmd? Why are you even trying to start a process from ASP.NET? It's impossible to help unless you provide *some* information.

Comment: It's normal web page by asp.net. No javascript code is written there.

Answer (score 0):

When showing the error message, write a javascript code so that after 10 seconds for example, it reloads your page with new controls.

Code behind:

```
lblError.Text = "Some Errors occured: ......etc";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), 
   "$(function() {setTimeout(function() {document.location='newpage.aspx';}, 10000);});", true);
```

Javascript code:

```
$(function(){
   setTimeout(function() {
     document.location='newpage.aspx';
   }, 10000);
});
```